# Bash does not recognize go after upgrading to Mac OS 10.9.3

Tags: macos, bash, go

Go was working fine on my computer before I upgraded to Mac OS 10.9.3.  Now, whenever I issue a go command (from an acceptable location), it says "-bash: go: command not found."

I checked my bash_profile, and everything is fine.  I sourced it with no issue.  When I execute: `echo $GOPATH`, it is correct.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this without having to completely reinstall golang?

Answer (score 1):

How did you install Go? The issue is not with `GOPATH` but with `PATH` itself.

If you installed from brew, make sure you have `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`. If you installed from sources, you need to have your `$GOBIN` and/or `$GOROOT/bin` in your `$PATH`.

If you don't know where go is, you can run `locate /bin/go` (you might want to run `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` before in order to update the locate database.) and add the location in your `$PATH`

Comment: I installed with brew, and /usr/local/bin is in my path.  If I uninstall via brew and reinstall, will my previously installed go packages get screwed up?  Forgive me for the "screwed up," I'm fairly new to Go and have no idea what will happen with a reinstall.

Comment: It depends on where you installed them. If you have your own $GOPATH, brew will not touch it. Can your try the locate command and make sure the go binary is there? If it is, you will have to reinstall go.

Comment: If you installed with Homebrew, add `export GOPATH=/path/to/your/preferred/Go/project/location` to `~/.bash_profile` and then type `source ~/.bash_profile` (to update your shell profile). i.e. `export GOPATH=/Documents/code/`

Comment: I ended up doing a complete reinstall of everything, wich obviously resolved my issues.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Lame I know but: Have you tried opening a new terminal window? I frequently have that issue when I install stuff with brew.